# DataBase connectivity in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, database-connectivity

In WordPress how to store the data submitted from a form to a database through php file? I used many plugins but still can't find the solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save data from an HTML form to a database table in WordPress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291581/how-to-save-data-from-an-html-form-to-a-database-table-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

for inserting any data from wordpress form to wordpress database you need to do this by manually code.
create a new file in wordpress theme template and use wp insert query on this page. 
currently we are developing a plugin for custom db insert in to database from admin, very soon we will upload it in wordpress free plugin list.

Comment: Thanks for the info bro!!